# Money sent to suspended cryptocurrency account at an exchange

Tags: cryptocurrency, europe, sepa

I have a cryptocurrency account at Binance account. However, as Binance no longer supports SEPA transfers, I recently opened another cryptocurrency account at *advcash*.

Before opening the account with *advcash*, I highlighted to them that my passport is from a restricted country but I am legally living in Schengen zone. I also asked whether I will be in any trouble, while in parallel they confirmed and verified my account.

On Thursday, I sent 200 EUR to my *advcash* account from Santander Bank. They [*advcash*/ Santander] said that due to high volume of transfers, SEPA transfers takes at least 3 business days.

The timeframe is okay for me. However, when I checked my *advcash* account yesterday, the system said, "Unfortunately, we are not currently offering our services to users from the country you selected." This was strange for me. While I am waiting for their response to my initial question on “whether I will be in any trouble”, I have the following questions in mind:

1. Does anybody have experience with *advcash*? They claimed that they are totally trusted.
2. In case my money is successfully deposited to their account, what will happen to my money given that they are not offering services to “the country I selected”? Should they refund it or can they withhold the money based on other facts?

Comment: No idea?.............

Comment: "They claimed that they are totally trusted." Do any scammers not claim this? I have never heard of advcash, but... come on, do you understand the problem here? I thought crypto was supposed to enable 'trustless' transacting, and yet when the rubber meets the road...

Comment: It was totally trusted. They turned back my money soon.

Comment: From they I mean most of its users. Of course. advancedcash which has been working with BINANCE for more than 3 years should be trusted